# Printing a batch of documents (images) at once

Tags: c#, .net, printing, batch-file, queue

I'm currently working on an application that is supposed to automatically print parsed images from a batch and have the batch refill itself when the batch becomes empty as long as the program is set to do so (user-input).

I've gotten as far as to get the images printed properly one by one through user input, but I can't seem to find any decent solution to printing several images at once without the interface locking up.

The idea I thought of myself was to either prepare the printerspool with an X amount of jobs at once and then invoke the Print() method to have the printer handle it from there or to append all the images into one document and send it as a single job. Then I also need to know the status of every card in the print-batch.

What can I do to make this happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am correct that you are being able to print images programatically and the problem is that UI freezes for that time?

Comment: Yes. That is the issue. I hoped that by just pushing the images onto the print queue, the printer would handle it from there and leave the UI operative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest, you simply put your printing code in a background thread, e.g. using [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Comment: I'm looking into it right now. Threading isn't something I'm very familiar with, but the code examples seem pretty straightforward.

Comment: I'm just wondering. Is it useful to set the BackgroundWorker as a class member? I'm currently calling the BackgroundWorker in a singleton object so other objects can reach it.

Comment: Yes, you can do that without a problem.

Comment: Right now I'm having issues with most likely accessing class members outside of the thread with this exception: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." It seems to be thrown when I try to access another singleton within my DoWork event handler. Can I circumvent this? What I do is first I set a property on the singleton and then I call a method. Perhaps it's a better idea to turn this property into a parameter of this method?

Comment: @Berry: Please ask a new question with more details.

Comment: I'll look for other answers first then.